# Discord.js i dont know ho to create Random Answers

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm new to programming and I want to know how to create a bot when you write !Random he answers I'm thinking and after 2 minutes he answers with a random response between Hello, Hi, Welcome.
Thanks to everyone
I don't ask for the complete code but maybe for some advice

Comment: Create an array of random responses and generate a random index each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Creating an array with answers.
const Answers = ["RandomAnswer1", "RandomAnswer2", "RandomAnswer3", "RandomAnswer4"];

// Picking a random answer every 1 second and logging it.
setInterval(() => {
    console.log(Answers[Math.floor(Math.random() * Answers.length)]);
}, 1000);
```